# MySQL Specify innodb_lock_wait_timeout for a specific query

Tags: mysql, database-locking

I'm using MySQL 5.6. I have a specific query in my application that I don't want to be subject to the global innodb_lock_wait_timeout setting. Is there any way that I can specify that this specific query should wait a different amount of time for a lock before timing out?

Answer (score 1):

You can only set this variable on [global or session level](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout), so you cannot set it just for a single query. Obviously, you can create a separate connection, set this variable on session level, execute your query and then close the connection.

You can find how to set a system variable on session level in [mysql documentation on set command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-statement.html):

> SET variable_assignment [, variable_assignment] ...
>
> variable_assignment:
>         user_var_name = expr
>       | [GLOBAL | SESSION] system_var_name = expr
>       | [@@global. | @@session. | @@]system_var_name = expr